# Why getting EOFError by using multiprocessing. Manager()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In Python, to share data between different process by using `multiprocessing`, we use `multiprocessing.Manager()`. I want to get output `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` in the following code, but I am getting EOFError. Why?
The Code is:

```
import multiprocessing
manager=multiprocessing.Manager()

final_list=manager.list()
input_list_one=[1,2,3,4,5]
input_list_two=[6,7,8,9,10]

def worker(data):
    for item in data:
        final_list.append(item)

process_1=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=[input_list_one])
process_2=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=[input_list_two])
process_1.start()
process_2.start()
process_1.join()
process_2.join()

print(final_list)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Process SyncManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 539, in _run_server
    server = cls._Server(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=16)
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 438, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 576, in __init__
    self._socket.bind(address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/.last_tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    manager=multiprocessing.Manager()
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/context.py", line 56, in Manager
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 517, in start
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
EOFError
1|u0_a823@land:/ $
```

Comment: Runs for me--I get the numbers in the final_list sometimes in a jumbled order.

Comment: yeah, the order may be changed...but why error?

Comment: @SupriyoHalder---I don't get an error so can't reproduce.  FYI--your post states you are getting  **EOFError** but your error log shows a **Permission denied** error.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue.
Here is my understanding of it:

- The child process tries to bind to the socket
  (line `self._socket.bind(address)`)
- It encounters a PermissionError while trying to access it and closes unexpectedly
- The Manager raises EOFError because the child process is not bound

---

On Linux, sockets are typically written in `/tmp/pymp-XXXXXXXX/listener-XXXXXXXX`.
I would therefore advise you to check that your process have the correct permissions for this folder.

I solved the permission denied error by setting the proper umask using `os.umask()` within the Python code.